# Scrapy runspider / how to use different settings?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

i have the following working spider as a process -
so i can start the spider with: python xyz.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

class onlyLinks(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'onlyLinks'
  allowed_domains = ['magnatiles.com']
  start_urls = ['https://www.magnatiles.com/products/page/1/']

  def parse(self, response):
    tmpProd = response.xpath("//ul[@class='products']//ancestor::li")
    for p in tmpProd:
      yield {
        "link": p.xpath("(./a)[1]/@href").get(),
        "name": p.xpath(".//h2/text()").get(),
        "sku": p.css("a.button::attr(data-product_sku)").get(),
        "price": p.xpath("//span[@class='price']//ancestor::bdi/text()").get()
      }

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
  "FEEDS": {
      "items.json": {"format": "json"},
      # "items.csv": {"format": "csv"},
      # "items.xlsx": {"format": "xlsx"},
  },
})

process.crawl(onlyLinks)
process.start()
```

But how can i use the other informations / settings from the settings.py?
eg. ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False, AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True, AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5 etc.

And how can i make the output to json in that way - so the output get overwritten?
(when i run the program now the data is allways appended to the existing items.json-file)
(when i run a spider with scrapy runspider i would use -o or -O to overwrite or not overwrite the output-file - but how can i do this here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using key value pairs meaning `dict` format as follows:

```
process = CrawlerProcess ({
    "FEEDS": {"items.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True}},
    'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY':'False',
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED':'True',
    'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': '5'
    })

process.crawl(onlyLinks)
process.start()
```

Comment: Ok thanks - but how to make the setting for overwriting json or Not?

Comment: Actually, scrapy doc didn't  make the setting for overwriting json

Comment: I have done an edit on the solution to show you how to overwrite the file.

Comment: Works great with the new parameter - thx